# laravel breeze force the user to enter password again after session expired

Tags: laravel, authentication, breeze

I am using laravel 9.0 with breeze for authentication
how can I ask the user to reenter the credentials after the session is expired

Answer (score 0):

You have many choices but if you want to check session validity on every request then you can use a middleware.

In your command console run:

```
php artisan make:middleware CheckSession
```

**CheckSession.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Auth;
use Session;

class CheckSession
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::user() &&  time() - Session::activity()) < (Config::get('session.lifetime') * 60) {
        return $next($request);
    }
    return redirect('/login')->with('error','Session expired! Please login again.');
    }
}
```

**app/Http/Kernel.php**
add this line to the  **protected $routeMiddleware** array:

```
'sessionChecker' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckSession::class,
```

**routes/web.php**
add your route middleware to every route that you want to check session validity for. for eaxample you have below route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::get('/products', 'ProductController@index')->name('products');
});
```

should be:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'sessionChecker']], function () {
        Route::get('/products', 'ProductController@index')->name('products');
    });
```

Comment: but this statement where should i put is in any controller sorry am new to laravel

Comment: I think it's better to create a middleware. But Laravel Authenticate middleware do it by default. why you want to ckeck session validity manually on every controller? You can adjust session lifetime in your .env file too.

Comment: I had changed the expiry time to 1 min its redirects only on one page not on the others, on the dashboard only I want to find the function where it check for the session time by defualt

Comment: I just edited my answer in order to your last comment. I hope this helps you solve the problem.